Is it possible to create a queue of transasctions?
I am wondering if it is possible to create a queue of transactions. In my case I want to add all incoming transactions to a queue and randomize which ones are completed and which ones are canceled. Does anyone know of any way to add all incoming transactions to a queue?

It is not possible to do it.
All transactions, including the ones going to your contract, are subject to be ordered by the validator, possible sorting in an order that maximize his profit with fees.
The EVM, that is an abstraction of a machine that execute the transactions, can only execute one at a time. It is like your contract receive the first transaction and execute it, after receive the second end execute it... and so on.
It is not possible to acumulate incoming transactions and execute them lately.

One wallet can be used to send only one transaction at a time, if you initiate a new txn, your earlier one should be rejected as there would be nonce mismatch.
